# Android Alert Dialog unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

> AlertFragment

```
public class AlertFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "DeliveryRequestErrMsg";

    private String mMsg;
    private String mTitle;
    private AlertDismissListener mAlertDismissListener;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new AlertDialog
                .Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(mTitle)
                .setMessage(mMsg)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cart_btn_dismiss, null)
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        mAlertDismissListener.onDismiss(this);
    }

    public AlertFragment title(String title) {
        this.mTitle = title;
        return this;
    }

    public AlertFragment msg(String mMsg) {
        this.mMsg = mMsg;
        return this;
    }

    public AlertFragment fragmentMgr(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        return this;
    }

    public AlertFragment onDismiss(AlertDismissListener alertDismissListener) {
        this.mAlertDismissListener = alertDismissListener;
        return this;
    }

    public void show() {
        try {
            super.show(mFragmentManager, getClass().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "show: ", e);
        }
    }

    interface AlertDismissListener {
        void onDismiss(AlertFragment fragment);
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return mMsg;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }
}
```

> AlertManagerImpl

```
public class AlertManagerImpl implements AlertManager {

        private List<AlertFragment> mListOfMessageShown = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public boolean isMessageDisplayed(@Nonnull String message) {
            boolean isAlreadyShown = false;
            for (AlertFragment deliveryRequestErrMsgFragment : mListOfMessageShown) {
                if (message.equals(deliveryRequestErrMsgFragment.getMsg())) {
                    isAlreadyShown = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return isAlreadyShown;
        }

        @Override
        public void showAlertMessage(@Nullable String title, String msg, FragmentActivity activity) {
            AlertFragment deliveryRequestErrMsgFragment = new AlertFragment()
                    .title(title)
                    .msg(msg)
                    .onDismiss(fragment -> mListOfMessageShown.remove(fragment))
                    .fragmentMgr(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            deliveryRequestErrMsgFragment.show();
            mListOfMessageShown.add(deliveryRequestErrMsgFragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void showAlertMessageWithoutDuplicates(@Nullable String title, String msg, FragmentActivity activity) {
            if (!isMessageDisplayed(msg)) {
                showAlertMessage(title, msg, activity);
            }
        }
    }
```

> AlertManager

```
    public interface AlertManager {

    /**
     * This method allow user to show multiple same alert messages
     *
     * @param title Title that need to show
     * @param msg Message that need to show
     * @param activity
     */
    void showAlertMessage(@Nullable String title, String msg, FragmentActivity activity);

    /**
     * This method does not allow user to show multiple same alert messages
     *
     * @param title Title that need to show
     * @param msg Message that need to show
     * @param activity
     */
    void showAlertMessageWithoutDuplicates(@Nullable String title, String msg, FragmentActivity activity);

    /**
     * Verify if there is already a similar message currently displayed to the user. Returns true if a similar message is already showing, else returns false
     *
     * @param message The message that we want to compare with the currently displayed alert messages
     * @return
     */
    boolean isMessageDisplayed(@Nonnull String message);

}
```

> AlertManagerImplTest

```
    @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = TestConfig.SDK)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class AlertManagerImplTest {
    @Inject
    AlertManager alertManager;
    @Inject
    Context mContext;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Module(
            includes = TestAppModule.class,
            injects = AlertManagerImplTest.class,
            overrides = true
    )
    static class TestModule {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mContext = RuntimeEnvironment.application;
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(mContext);
        Services.initialize(new AlertManagerImplTest.TestModule()).inject(this);
        mainActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkMessageDisplayed_WhenSameMessage_ShouldReturnTrue() throws Exception {
        alertManager.showAlertMessage("Title1", "Message1", mainActivity);
        Assert.assertTrue(alertManager.isMessageDisplayed("Message1"));
    }

    @Test
    public void checkMessageDisplayed_WhenDifferentMessage_ShouldReturnFalse() throws Exception {
        alertManager.showAlertMessage("Title1", "Message1", mainActivity);
        Assert.assertFalse(alertManager.isMessageDisplayed("Message2"));
    }
}
```

> Here I have created AlertManager to use in my project. So implementation is working properly. But now I'm facing a challenge that I need to write some Unit testing for this implementation. Especially I need to test the following scenarios

- show one alert -> Verify if it is showing
- try to show one alert with a "dead" activity -> Verify that no crash occurs
- show 10 alerts -> Verify that all 10 are shown (to verify that we can trust the method in most of the cases)

> I created a test class to just test one function of AlertManagerImpl
>   class. I need to actually verify alert is showing. I read some post
>   and someone suggested that Robolectric is good for this but I not good
>   at Unit testing if you can suggest any other solution also welcome. If someone help with this to me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

actually what you've done so far (`AlertManagerImplTest`) is not a unit test. This is more likley an integration test, because it runs with Robolectric, initializes your application and runs on a device or emulator.

If you want to test your `AlertManagerImpl` in a real unit test, you should write some plain JUnit test and mock/stub out all the dependencies your `AlertManagerImpl` uses (`FragmentActivity`, `AlertFragment`).
You may write your own mock/stub classes or use a mocking framework like Mockito. If you further wanna mock calls like `new AlertFragment()`, you will have to use a more powerful mocking framework like PowerMock. Also you may consider to refactor your code (e.g. use dependency injection), so you will not have to use PowerMock.